# How to access data bytes of an JPEG image in order to encrypt it?

Tags: c++, image-processing, encryption, cryptography, jpeg

For a project I need to encrypt data bytes of an JPEG image in order to show both encrypted and decrypted image. I used to done this with BMP format easily by skipping 1078 bytes then encrypted rest. But for JPEG it's a lot harder. I found that JPEG has [20 byte markers](https://www.file-recovery.com/jpg-signature-format.htm) but when I skip 20 bytes instead of 1078 I can't see the encrypted image as I did with BMP.

So can you tell me how can I access data bytes in JPEG format in order to encrypt it ?

Note:Code is a lot larger so I can't post whole code. The info on how to access data bytes in JPEG format would be sufficient.

Comment: Why don't you encrypt the whole file, including the header?

Comment: @grooveplex I need the header to be intact in order to do some conversion. After that I send the image using sockets. Since the actual program is a lot larger than the code above its a little bit complex to explain .Basically I need to image to look like encrypted JPEG image. Plus when I recieve the image on the other side I'll still have to know the header in order to show the encrypted image.Which is a must for my project. Btw sorry for my English.

Comment: It would help if you could [edit] your question to include a complete runnable program, not just a snippet.

Comment: @grooveplex The whole code is a lot larger than this would it be ok if I posted github link ?

Comment: No it probably wouldn't. Questions need to be able to withstand the test of time and remain coherent while links rot. If the content of the link is required to understand the question, the question is no longer coherent after the link is gone.

Comment: jpeg is a compressed format. Without the header to assist in decompression, the image data is meaningless. If the compressed data is encrypted, good luck being able to decompress it into an image--even a garbage image. If you want to show the image, you're probably better off decompressing it into a bitmap, and then doing whatever you do for a bitmap.

Comment: @user4581301 The problem is I don't need anything but info on how to access data bytes in JPEG format which is the question. So even I posted the whole code it would just make the question a lot harder to understand.

Comment: @user4581301 hmm. I really need the garbage image and I need to reduce the size of the image because performance in my project is  a important factor. Any other advices ?

Comment: Do you create the images yourself? If so, can't you just run the encryption on the uncompressed image buffer and then compress it to jpeg afterwards?

Comment: @Timo Compression doesn't work well on randomized data, and ciphertext does look like random data without the key. Moreover, JPEG is lossy compression, so you wouldn't be able to exactly reduce the ciphertext. Maybe you could store the ciphertext in the header and reduce the JPEG to a single bit or something similar.

Comment: @Tİmo I get images from camera plus what Maarten Bodewes said I guess.

Answer (score 2):

The JPEG format is much more complex than a simple bitmap. In addition to image data, a JPEG can contain comments, metadata, and probably some other info that I'm not aware of. (Images from a camera almost certainly include metadata, such as where and when the image was taken.) There is structure beyond the header bytes. If you want to change the data within a JPEG and have the result be a valid JPEG, you would need to be able to read and write the JPEG structure.

As I understand it – and my understanding is far from complete – a JPEG file consists of a sequence of segments. Each segment starts with the marker byte `FF` followed by a byte that indicates what kind of segment it is. For some kinds of segments, this is followed by two bytes indicating how long the data of the segment is (the length includes the length bytes, but does not include the marker and kind bytes). For example, the file starts with the segment `FF` `D8`, a 2-byte segment (no length bytes) that indicates the start of the image. This is followed by another segment. The page you linked to gives example data where the next segment is an application segment: `FF` `E0` followed by 16 bytes of data. How do you know there are 16 bytes of data? The first two of those bytes are `00` `10`, which is 16 in decimal. After that comes another `FF` marker, signalling another segment.

```
FF D8
FF E0 00 10 4A 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 48 00 48 00 00
FF DB 00 43 [65 bytes of data]
...
```

To retain the JPEG format, you should process the file in terms of segments. Drop the idea of having a (20-byte) file header; there is simply a sequence of segments. Some of the segments play the role of header data and should not be modified without a deeper understanding of the format. Other segments contain the data you want to modify.
I think the segments you are interested in are the frames, which are kinds `C0` through `CF` minus `C4` and `CC`. These segments have variable-length data, hence their data begins with a two-byte length. If you're lucky, modifying just the data in these segments will get you the results you want. If you're not lucky, there is critical additional structure within this data that I'm not aware of, and your modifications will corrupt that structure.

What you might want to do is scan the file looking for a marker byte, `FF`. Look at the byte after that. Is it a kind you want to modify? If not, just copy bytes until you reach the next marker. If it is a kind to modify, read the next two bytes to get the length of the data. Then read (length-2) bytes, remembering that you already read 2 bytes. This is the data to process. After processing, re-calculate the length then write the segment (`FF` followed by the kind, followed by the new length, followed by the modified data). Keep going until you run out of file to process.

There is a complication to keep in mind, hinted at by "re-calculate the length". If the byte `FF` appears somewhere in the modified data, you'll need to flag it as not a marker by inserting the null byte, `00`, after it. This is one way the length could change.

If you're still following, you might be able to pull this off. I can point you to [a copy of the JPEG standard](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/itu-t81.pdf), which is a rough read. Still, it has a list of kinds of segments in its Table B.1 (the 36th page, but numbered 32). Remember that your encryption is of the file, not of the image. To decrypt the data, you will need the encrypted file, not merely the image it produces.

Comment: Thanks for this advice! I assumed roughly the same as the original poster's. I'll do this as a small project, publicly available. But for now, I'll simply just convert my JPGs into Bitmap.